# replace value AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, input, replace, angular-directive

Хотелось бы вырезать смайлы при вводе в импут (в рантайме).
Создал директиву, линканул. Проблема - первый введенный смайл вырезает, на второй введенный не реагирует, на третий вырезает два. Если заменяю в реплейсе пустые кавычки на "1", отрабатывает хорошо, каждый смайл реплейсит на 1.

Есть ли у кого мысли? буду благодарен!

```js
(function () {
  angular.module('LoyaltyApp')
    .directive('filter', function () {
      return {

        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

          // create the regex obj. for emoji signs
          var regex = new RegExp('(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])', 'g');

          // add a parser that will process each time the value is
          // parsed into the model when the user updates it.
          ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
            console.log('value', value);
            var valid = value.replace(regex, "");
            console.log('replace Value (valid)', valid);
            if(value !== valid){
              ctrl.$viewValue = valid;

            }
            ctrl.$render();
            return valid;
          });
        }
      };
    });
})();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы повесил на `input` встроенную директиву [ngPattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern). Получилось бы что-то типа такого:

**html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="..." required ng-pattern="textWithoutSmilesPattern" />
```

**js controller**

```
$scope.textWithoutSmilesPattern = "/^.*[^(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])].*$/";
```

**Работает так:** если где-то в тексте встречается текст по вашему `regex` (какой-либо смайлик), то это поле будет считаться неправильно заполненным. Форма не отправится.